# Manifest error for anonymous type

Tags: scala

I am still getting my head around Scala, so trying to figure out what is missing in below code. I am getting this error message when i try to instantiate genericserializer with anonymous type

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type type mismatch;  found   :
>   scala.reflect.Manifest[Object]  required:
>   scala.reflect.Manifest[FolderMgmtDAO.this.anoMoveType] Note: Object >:
>   FolderMgmtDAO.this.anoMoveType, but trait Manifest is invariant in
>   type T. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >:
>   FolderMgmtDAO.this.anoMoveType`. (SLS
>   3.2.10)   FolderMgmtDAO.scala /somucore/src/somu/core line 20 Scala Problem

Below is the code

```
object GenericSerializer
{
  def apply[T <:AnyRef:Manifest]() = new GenericSerializer[T]()
}

class GenericSerializer[T <:AnyRef:Manifest] extends IMongoSerializer[T] {} 

//Anonymous type creation and using GenericSerializer
    type anoMoveType = { def folderPath:String } 
        val szr = GenericSerializer[anoMoveType]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4252?focusedCommentId=57917&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-57917) it's not possible with manifests.
You should use `TypeTag` instead. Like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
object GenericSerializer
{
  def apply[T <:AnyRef]()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = {}
}
```