# How to use anonymous types when Manifest type is required

Tags: scala

I am not familiar with the Manifest type. The Jackson library uses this type, i.e. in ObjectMapper. So given this method:

```
def fromJson[T: Manifest](jsonInputStream: InputStream): T
```

I tried to call it with an anonymous type like:

```
....fromJson[{val numRounds: Int; val numSeconds: Int }](json)
```

but I got a compile error.

```
[error]  found   : scala.reflect.Manifest[Object]
[error]  required: Manifest[AnyRef{val numRounds: Int; val numSeconds: Int}]
[error] Note: Object >: AnyRef{val numRounds: Int; val numSeconds: Int}, but trait Manifest is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: AnyRef{val numRounds: Int; val numSeconds: Int}`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]           val d = jsonParser.fromJson[{val numRounds: Int; val numSeconds: Int}](json)
```

Can someone explain the problem here? Do I really have to create a proper class for the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered your question in [Manifest error for anonymous type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483433/manifest-error-for-anonymous-type/23675889#23675889) :

> [Looks like](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4252?focusedCommentId=57917&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-57917) it's not possible with manifests. You should use
>   `TypeTag` instead. Like this:
>
> ```
> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
> object GenericSerializer
> {
>   def apply[T <:AnyRef]()(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = {}
> }
> ```